# Multiple Redux middleware causing Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am getting

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at eval (index.js?4bd6:38)
    at Object.dispatch (applyMiddleware.js?6ce6:35)
    at dispatchChildActions (index.js?4bd6:33)
    at eval (index.js?4bd6:39)
    at Object.dispatch (applyMiddleware.js?6ce6:35)
    at dispatchChildActions (index.js?4bd6:33)
    at eval (index.js?4bd6:39)
    at Object.dispatch (applyMiddleware.js?6ce6:35)
    at dispatchChildActions (index.js?4bd6:33)
```

When I try to add `redux-batched-actions` middleware into my `applyMiddleware()`

```
const store = createStore(
  enableBatching(appReducer), // added enableBatching
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(
      batchDispatchMiddleware, // and this
      sagaMiddleware,
      historyMiddleware,
    )
  )
)
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I took the time to go through the source code for you. It was a package bug. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions/pull/22).

A previous merge was causing an infinite recursion, where non-batched actions were repeatedly being dispatched. I also think you should only use the middleware or the higher order reducer depending on your use case, see the ReadMe for a small explanation.
Please try out the fix and let me know as I do not have a project currently set up.

Hope this solves your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure.

Here is the code that works for me, maybe it will help:

```
const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === 'object' &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ ?
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
    }) : compose;

const enhancers = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
  autoRehydrate()
);

const initialState = {};
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  initialState,
  compose(enhancers)
);
persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/xxx" component={XXX} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
      </Container>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errror when forgit to wrap my actions in curly braces:

```
return bindActionCreators(...TaskActions, ...UserActions, dispatch)
```

instead of

```
return bindActionCreators({...TaskActions, ...UserActions}, dispatch)
```